# Passing a variable number of generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, contravariance, covariant

to be specific, I want to write an export function which I can use like this:

```
List<HistoryBook> HistoryBooks = something;
List<MathBook> MathBooks = something;
List<ScienceBook> ScienceBooks = something;

ExcelExporter.Export(FileName, HistoryBooks, MathBooks, ScienceBooks);
```

I thought about something like the code below, but in this case I have to cast everything to a "List of object" which is not what I want.

```
public void Export(string FileName, params List<object>[] Data)
```

Can you give me a hint how to solve this elegantly?

Comment: Do `HistoryBook` `MathBook` and `ScienceBook` inherit from the same class, say `Book`?

Comment: Maybe you want the books to inherit from a `Book` class?

Comment: Yes, Make the classes inherit from BaseClass Book or Implement an Interface called Book and then the parameter of the method will be BaseClass Type or Interface Type

Comment: Not necessarily. They should all inherit from object, don't they?

Comment: No, all the classes dont inherit from Class object. It depends on your HistoryBook, MathBook declarations.

Comment: For the cause see: [question-about-c-sharp-covariance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034495/question-about-c-sharp-covariance)

Comment: Very similiar [can-i-have-a-variable-number-of-generic-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612887/can-i-have-a-variable-number-of-generic-parameters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you say, you want to be able to pass completely unrelated lists, maybe you should accept the base IList interface:

```
public void Export(string FileName, params IList[] Data)
```

All `List<T>` objects implement `IList`, as well as the generic `IList<T>`, so you can enforce that.

Actually, depending on what you need to do with these lists in the Exporter, perhaps enforcing `IEnumerable` is enough for you, if all you need is forward-only read-once functionality.

Best way to decide is to determine what the shared functionality you need for all parameters, and define your method signature to enforce that functionality.

*UPDATE*

Based on your comment, it seems what you want is possible in C# 4.0 using covariant/contravariant generics, meaning that a generic `ISomething<out object>` could receive an `ISomething<string>`. The problem is that `IList<T>` doesn't define a covariant generic parameter, so passing `IList<string>` for `IList<object>` doesn't work.

However, `IList<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<out T>`, which DOES define a covariant parameter. So if your `Export` method receives a `params IEnumerable<object>[] data` parameter, you SHOULD be able to pass it any `IList<T>` you want.

Comment: That goes in the direction I wanted. BUT. I want to - somehow - make sure that every item in an IList is of the same type. Thats why I wanted to ensure it by using a generic type list.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution, I think.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Book {}

class ScienceBook : Book {}

class MathBook : Book  {}

class ScienceBook : Book {}

public void Export(string FileName, IList<Book> Data)
```

or you can use interface for it.
e.g. 
    interface IBook {}

Comment: Thanks, but they can be different baseclasses. I just want to drop random Lists of stuff into this function and the function uses reflection and the DisplayName-Attribute to output it into an Excel-File.

Comment: then you can use an interface instead of an inheritance.

Comment: yes. as per below, you may require overloads. you could also create a different wrappers with the interface IBook/IExport . Possibly, have an enum to determine the type for easy conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
   public interface IBook {}

   public class ScienceBook : IBook {} 
   public class MathBook: IBook {}
   public class HistoryBook: IBook {}

    class Main()
    {
      List<IBook> hbook = new List<HistoryBook>();
      List<IBook> mbook = new List<MathBook>();
      List<IBook> sbook = new List<ScienceBook> ();

      public void Export(string FileName, List<IBook> Data)


    }
```

Comment: What if I want to export a List<TextBox> - just in case ;-)

Comment: If the case isn't limited to Generic types, you may not be able to solve this with single method (without much complexity). I think you may need method overloads in that case.