# Can you write a c# decorator function that can take any number of arguments?

Tags: c#, wrapper, decorator

I currently have code which acts much like a python decorator, it takes a function as argument and returns the same function wrapped by another (in this case opening and closing a perforce connection).

```
    public Func<TArg, TReturn> EnableP4<TReturn, TArgs>(Func<TArg, TReturn> function)
    {
        Func<TArg, TReturn> p4Wrapper = (TArg funcArg) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.Status.Equals(ConnectionStatus.Disconnected)) { con.Connect(options); }
                return function(funcArg);
            }
            finally { con.Disconnect(); }
        };
        return p4Wrapper;
    }
```

At the moment this only works for functions with one argument and I was wondering if it could be made more general (maybe if there is a way of unpacking an array into a method?).

(Something along the lines of this?)

```
    public Func<TArgs, TReturn> EnableP4<TReturn, TArgs>(Func<TArgs, TReturn> function)
    {
        Func<TArgs, TReturn> p4Wrapper = (TArgs args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.Status.Equals(ConnectionStatus.Disconnected)) { con.Connect(options); }
                return function(*args);
            }
            finally { con.Disconnect(); }
        };
        return p4Wrapper;
    }
```

where TArgs is a TArg[].

Comment: Can you give an illustration of how you intend to use this? I'm not quite sure I understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `Func<T>` (not `Func<TArg,TResult>`), and allow the compiler to handle the multiple arguments via closures in lambda expressions for you.

If you changed your method to:

```
public Func<T> EnableP4<T>(Func<T> function)
```

You could always call it via:

```
var newFunc = EnableP4(() => SomeFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

This is nice in that it allows any number of arguments without having multiple overloads.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can'd do exactly this in C# with strongly typed results. It is mainly due to return type - you can relatively easy construct calling of the function with arbitrary number of parameters (i.e. Emit or reflection), but to have strongly typed result you'll have to have multiple functions.

Usual approach is to have multiple functions for each of 0-n (often 0-3 is enough) number of arguments.

```
public Func<TReturn> EnableP4<TReturn>(Func<T1, TReturn> function)...
public Func<T1, TReturn> EnableP4<TReturn, T1>(Func<T1, TReturn> function)....
public Func<T1, T2, TReturn> 
        EnableP4<TReturn, T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, TReturn> function)...
```

Notes:

- you may experiment with `dynamic` to see if you get close to what you want
- also Dependency Injection frameworks (like Unity) allows you to wrap all methods in an interface/class, so in some cases it may work (probably not this case as it looks like it is for some sort of refactoring of code inside a data access layer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass all the arguments in; instead, you can pass a lambda that already has the arguments supplied to it.

This is most easily explained via an example. Given this:

```
public Func<T> Wrapper<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    Func<T> wrapper = () =>
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Prequel");
            return function();
        }

        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sequel");
        }
    };

    return wrapper;
}
```

You can do this:

```
    void run()
    {
        // Supply arguments to test() here:
        var wrapped = Wrapper(() => test(1, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(wrapped());
    }

    private int test(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test()");
        return a + b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable number of type arguments is [unsupported in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612887/can-i-have-a-variable-number-of-generic-parameters), so I think it's impossible to do what you want with what you currently have. There is a reason the .Net framework itself has [that many func/action delegate declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.aspx). This is also visible with Tuples, on the same namespace.

I think you could work around it using a parameter object, which is basically a class that encapsulates all of your parameters. If you then create a base class or interface for these models, you could restrict your decorator method:

```
public Func<TArgs, TReturn> EnableP4<TReturn, TArgs>(Func<TArgs, TReturn> function)
    where TArgs : IArgs
```

This is quite similar to the concept used in events inside the framework, where an EventArgs parameter object is passed around. The idea here is the same, you would have to inherit the base model/interface and create the specific model with the parameters you want.

This is not optimal of course because it requires a lot of modifications and is nonstandard for simple method calls, but I think it should work nicely.

Have you considered method interception for this though? I know [Unity supports it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx) for instance.